# AngularJS: Summing nested objects from multiple objects

Tags: angularjs

Based in the following [table](http://plnkr.co/edit/7M67X961gK0e6DekWdJ7?p=preview) I need to get the total of all subtotals.

I have tried to use the same *sumByKey* filter but I does't work.
Plus, the sum of all subtotals must be based on the result of the filter, it means, If we have two results (two categories) the sum of subtotals must be based on those objects. Any idea?

**html**

```
<table border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>Category</th>
      <th>Products with quantities</th>
      <th>Subtotal of quantities</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody align="center">
    <tr data-ng-repeat="category in categories | filter:search">
      <td>{{$index+1}}</td>
      <td>{{category.name}}</td>
      <td>{{category.products}}</td>
      <td>{{category.products | sumByKey:'quantity'}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <thead align="right">
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3"><strong>Total</strong></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

**angularjs**

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);
app.controller("controllerApp", function($scope, $http){
    $http.get("categories.json").success(function(data) {
        $scope.categories = data;
     });
});

app.filter('sumByKey', function () {
    return function (data, key) {
        if (typeof (data) === 'undefined' || typeof (key) === 'undefined') {
      return 0;
    }
    var sum = 0;
    for (var i = data.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        sum += parseInt(data[i][key]);
    }
    return sum;
}
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done with angular also.

Example : http://plnkr.co/edit/zhTtoOjW7J1oumktlvFP?p=preview

HTML:

```
<table border="1">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>#</th>
          <th>Category</th>
          <th>Products with quantities</th>
          <th>Subtotal of quantities</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody align="center">
        <tr data-ng-repeat="category in filterValues=(categories | filter:search)">
          <td>{{$index+1}}</td>
          <td>{{category.name}}</td>
          <td>{{category.products}}</td>
          <td>{{category.products | sumByKey:'quantity'}}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
      <thead align="right">
        <tr>
          <td colspan="3"><strong>Total</strong></td>
          <td>{{filterValues | sumOfValue:'quantity'}}</td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
    </table>
```

JS:

```
// Code goes here
var app = angular.module("app", []);
app.controller("controllerApp", function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get("categories.json").success(function(data) {
    $scope.categories = data;
  });
});

app.filter('sumByKey', function() {
  return function(data, key) {
    if (typeof(data) === 'undefined' || typeof(key) === 'undefined') {
      return 0;
    }
    var sum = 0;
    for (var i = data.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      sum += parseInt(data[i][key]);
    }
    return sum;
  }
});

app.filter('sumOfValue', function() {
  return function(data, key) {
    if (angular.isUndefined(data) || angular.isUndefined(key)) {
      return 0;
    }
    var sum = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      var value = data[i];
      if (!angular.isUndefined(value)) {
        for (var j = 0; j < value.products.length; j++) {
          sum += parseInt(value.products[j][key]);
        }
      }
    }
    return sum;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

May not be `Angular` solution. But you can also get total by pure `JavaScript`.

By keeping a `total` `$scope` varaible like this inside your `controller`

```
     $scope.total = getTotal(data);
     function getTotal(data){
       var total = 0;
       data.forEach(function(item){
         item.products.forEach(function(product){
           total += product.quantity;
         })
       });
       return total;
     }
```

[Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/j1qKrGbmYSFkOJznx5Fk?p=preview) is the updated `Plunker`.

Comment: When I filter the categories the 'total' must be based on the filtered objects. Try to use the filter in order to see the total. Any idea? By the way thanks for your answer.