# AngularJS : How to sum similar variables from multilpe arrays

Tags: angularjs

Please see what I need to do at the end of this question.

I have the following relationship between Category and Products (1-n).

[image]

This is the html table with the inventory

```
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Category</th>
        <th>Products quantity</th>
    </tr>   
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr data-ng-repeat="category in categories" data-ng-repeat="getProductsByCategory(category)">
        <td>{{category.name}}</td>
        <td>{{products[category.id] | sumByKey:'quantity'}}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
<tfooter>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">total</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</footer>
```

And this is the result, as you can see I'm using the *'sumByKey'* filter in order to get the sum of all products by its category

[image]

The respective function to get all products by its category

```
$scope.products = [];
$scope.getProductsByCategory = function(category){
    $http.get("getProductsByCategory/"+category.id)
    .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.products[category.id] = data;
    })
    .error(function (data, status, header, config) {
        $log.error("Error");
    });
};
```

And the filter to sum all quantities

```
app.filter("sumByKey", function() {
    return function(data, key) {
    if (typeof(data) === 'undefined' || typeof(key) === 'undefined') {
        return 0;
    }
    var sum = 0;
    for (var i = data.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        sum += parseInt(data[i][key]);
    }
    return sum;
    };
});
```

**In order to get the total in the inventory table I have been trying to use the same filter (*sumByKey*) but it doesn't work. Any idea to get the respective result?**

Comment: As it appears you're making an Api call, I would _highly_ recommend doing this in the database, in your stored procedure call or view. Then you can bring it down as part of your response data.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40697761/3279156  ----- This can help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that $scope.products will be [ProductArrayCat1, ProductArrayCat2,ProductArrayCat3]

So all you have to do is throw the 3 arrays to the sumByKey filter respectively.

```
<tfooter>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2">total</td>
    <td>{{total}}</td>
</tr>
```

```
$scope.total=0;
$scope.getProductsByCategory $scope.getProductsByCategory= function(category){
$http.get("getProductsByCategory/"+category.id)
.success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    $scope.products[category.id] = data;
    $scope.total += $filter('sumByKey')(data,'quantity');
});
};
```

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is call the filter in the controller and add the results to a total.

```
$scope.total = 0;

$scope.sum = function(value) {
    var results = // sum returned by your filter;

    // maintains count of all category sums
    $scope.total += results;

    // amount that goes back to the view
    return results; 
}
```

Then just bind $scope.total to your view.

```
<td>{{products[category.id] | sum('quantity')}}</td>
```